# google places api not working for meteor

Tags: javascript, google-maps, meteor

```
Template.home.onCreated(function() {
    // We can use the `ready` callback to interact with the map API once the map is ready.
    GoogleMaps.ready('Map', function(map) {
        // Add a marker to the map once it's ready
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: map.options.center,
            map: map.instance
        });

        var request = {
            location: map.options.center,
            radius:10000,
            types:['restaurant']
        }

        console.log(request)

        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch(request,callback);
        console.log("Calling Service")

        function callback(results,status)
        {
            console.log("Service Called")

            if(status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK)
            {
                console.log("Status OK")
                for(var i = 0;i < results.length;i++)
                {
                    console.log(results[i])
                    createMarker(results[i]);

                }
            }
        }//end of callback

        function createMarker(place)
        {
            var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map:map,
                position:place.geometry.location
            });
        }//end of create marker

    })//end of google maps.ready function
});
```

I have a simple application meant to search for places and place markers on the results in the map. The map renders properly, and I have tried the same setup on a normal html and js app. I am having trouble implementing it in my meteor app. The application stops once it reaches the `var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);` call, and I get this error on my console `Uncaught TypeError: this.j.getElementsByTagName is not a function`. I am using the `dburles:google-maps` package.

Comment: Can you try putting your code in `Template.home.onRendered` instead of `Template.home.onCreated`. `onRendered` will be called once your UI is ready, where are `onCreated` is called before the UI loads completely. This is a guess, since I don't know much about google places api.

Comment: `var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map.instance);`

Comment: i did that and it worked but now my markers arent showing up. i know i am getting the locations cos i am logging them to the console but the markers arent being created on the map

Comment: You need **map.instance** again instead of map in your createMarker function. var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map:map.instance,
                position:place.geometry.location
            });

Comment: @mwarren i did that already. it still doesn't show my marker except for the initial marker showing the users location.

Comment: @shekhar did you ever find a solution? I am running into this issue now.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing map to **new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map)** when you need to pass map.instance **new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map.instance)**

See the link for reference https://github.com/dburles/meteor-google-maps#ready